# java playframework syntax! what does it actually means?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am trying to learn the playframework 2 and having problems with understanding the code. I tried to search any definitions but unfortunately can't find.

Here is a sample code

```
// Find all tasks
List<Task> tasks = Task.find.all();

// Find a task by ID
Task anyTask = Task.find.byId(34L);

// Delete a task by ID
Task.find.ref(34L).delete();

// More complex task query
List<Task> tasks = find.where()
    .ilike("name", "%coco%")
    .orderBy("dueDate asc")
    .findPagingList(25)
    .getPage(1);
```

I would like to ask what does it exactly means ?

```
List<Task> tasks = Task.find.all();
```

and is there a good source available to learn play! 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play is having a ORM(Ebean) underneath.So the code refered by you: List tasks = Task.find.all(); is roughly equivalent to List< T > findAll(); http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introquery.html

What its doing its making a List name tasks of all Task objects.Its roughly equilveant to Select * from TASK(assuming you have a Task Table)

And for your second part of question:Playframeowrk doc is good place to start:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaHome

Comment: Actually Playframework 2.0 uses Ebean as the default ORM for Java not Hibernate.  Please look at Ebean documentation.

http://www.avaje.org/